# Removing all spaces recursively (list of list of lists of...)

Tags: python, recursion, space

I'm trying to remove all spaces from the input which is list of list of lists... I don't know what to do for the "else:"

```
def removespace(lst):
   if type(lst) is str:
      return lst.replace(" ","")
   else:
      ?????
```

*Example:*

```
lst = [ apple, pie ,    [sth, [banana     , asd, [    sdfdsf, [fgg]]]]]
```

The output should be:

```
lst2 = [apple,pie,[sth,[banana,asd,[sdfdsf,[fgg]]]]]
```

and what to do if the lst contains integers or floating points? I have received errors for integers.

example input :

```
 L = [['apple', '2 * core+1* sth'], ['pie', '1*apple+1*sugar+1*water'], ['water', 60]]
```

Comment: Post those lists in the question body.

Comment: Your example list is not a valid Python code.

Comment: In your example, Python will see your list as a python list, and apple, pie, etc, must be variables. There is no string here. It's certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def removespace(a):
    if type(a) is str:
        return a.replace(" ", "")
    elif type(a) is list:
        return [removespace(x) for x in a]
    elif type(a) is set:
        return {removespace(x) for x in a}
    else:
        return a
```

Here is a sample:

```
>>> removespace([["a ",["   "]],{"b ","c d"},"e f g"])
[['a', ['']], {'b', 'cd'}, 'efg']
```

Comment: @thg435. isinstance would be better, but I used the same code as the OP. For those who are interested : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to follow EAFP and catch an exception instead of using `isinstance`. Also, never miss an opportunity to make a function a bit more generic:

```
def rreplace(it, old, new):
    try:
        return it.replace(old, new)
    except AttributeError:
        return [rreplace(x, old, new) for x in it]
```

Example:

```
a = [" foo", ["    spam", "ham"], "  bar"]
print rreplace(a, " ", "")
```

Or even more generic, although that might be an overkill for your problem:

```
def rapply(it, fun, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return fun(it, *args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        return [rapply(x, fun, *args, **kwargs) for x in it]

a = [" foo", ["    spam", "ham"], "  bar"]
print rapply(a, str.replace, " ", "")     
print rapply(a, str.upper)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def removespace(lst):
    if type(lst) is str:
        return lst.replace(" ","")
    else:
        return [removespace(elem) for elem in lst]



lst = [' apple', 'pie ', ['sth', ['banana', 'asd', [' sdfdsf', ['fgg']]]]] 
print removespace(lst)
```

prints

```
['apple', 'pie', ['sth', ['banana', 'asd', ['sdfdsf', ['fgg']]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you may experiment with recursive solution, but you can try your hand on a wonderful library Python provides, to transform a well formed Python literal from string to Python literal.

- Just convert you list to string
- remove any necessary spaces
- and then reconvert to the recursive list structure using [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

  ```
  >>> lst = [' apple', 'pie ', ['sth', ['banana', 'asd', [' sdfdsf', ['fgg']]]]]
  >>> import ast
  >>> ast.literal_eval(str(lst).translate(None,' '))
  ['apple', 'pie', ['sth', ['banana', 'asd', ['sdfdsf', ['fgg']]]]]
  ```